# Excel - Count specific named folders

Tags: vba, excel, count, directory

I am not very good at VBA. I am trying to create a function which counts how many sub-folders are in a folder that start with `3`, so for example:

`C:\Files\ <This is the main folder>`

If there was only one sub-folder named `32156` it would return a result of `1`

I found a lot of scripts which count sub-folders but not familiar enough to amend them.

Comment: And what's wrong with those sample scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Sub TestCalling()
        MsgBox fGetFolderCount("C:\Files", "3")
    End Sub



    Function fGetFolderCount(ByVal FolderPath As String, Optional ByVal Prefix As String = vbNullString) As Long

        Dim D As Variant
        Dim C As Long
        D = Dir(FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & Prefix & "*", vbDirectory)

        While D <> ""
            If Left(D, 1) <> "." Then
                C = C + 1
            End If
            D = Dir
        Wend

        fGetFolderCount = C

    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Arya, how do I call this function though in the spreadsheet? Should I just assign to a button (sorry probably a very lame question, still learning)

Comment: Hi Jayson - you can put this function in a module and call in a cell passing the arguments as required, or you can call this function as i call in a proc  like i called in **TestCalling**